# Method to grep multiple folders via a regex search term

Tags: regex, bash, grep, glob

I currently have a bash script to grep multiple folders of .txt files. The folder structure looks like this:

```
20200801
20200802
20200803
20200804
20200805
20200806
20200807
20200808
20200809
20200810
20200811
20200812
20200813
20200814
20200815
20200816
20200817
20200818
20200819
20200820
20200821
20200822
20200823
20200824
20200825
20200826
20200827
20200828
```

I have

```
read -p "Enter date: " Date
```

and

```
grep -r -h -P "$SearchKey" /mnt/f/Files/August2020/$Date
```

for a date input where i can input the date as

```
2020080[1-9]
```

to grep all folders between `1st` and `9th`of the month. However if I attempt

```
202008(0[1-9]|1[0-9])
```

the extended regex doesn't seem to work. I am looking for a way to be able to search within any dates I want.

Comment: use `find` and `grep` something like `find . -type d -name "2020080*" -exec grep -r -h -P "$SearchKey"  {} \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need extglob shell option and @ operator:

```
shopt -s extglob 
echo 202008@(0[1-9]|1[0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the range `{01-19}`, you don't need a `regex` for that, you can use `bash` brace expansion, it works for fixed width numbers also:

```
for i in {01..19}; do printf "%s " "$i"; done
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

so this works:

```
grep -r pattern dir/202008{01..19}/*
```

---

Here is a way to give a date range in the strict form of `01..20` and to `grep` for it. Please note that `eval` is used here, which is evil, and in general introduces secutiry risk for command injection.

```
s="text"
prefix=/mnt/f/Files/August2020/202008

read -p "Enter date range (example:01..10) " d
[[ "$d" =~ ^[0-9]{2}[\.]{2}[0-9]{2}$ ]] && grep -r "$s" $( eval echo $prefix{$d} )
```

Comment: Hello i tried that and it works when being input on commandline. However in bash script it gives me the No such file or directory found error

Comment: I used this in commandline which works `grep -r -h pattern /mnt/f/Files/August2020/202008{01..11} > out.txt`

However this in script doesn't

`grep -r -h $SearchKey /mnt/f/Files/August2020/202008{$Date} > out.txt`
My input for $Date variable is 01..11

Comment: You have a variable in the place of the brace expansion. Why don't you print this to see what exists there? `d="01..11"; echo {$d}` you see, it is not expanding.

Comment: Hmm yes it isnt expanding. Is there however a way to achieve what i originally wanted then? I want to be able to input dates on script for the grep

Comment: In your question, what will be the input "Date" providing by the user? a date? a range? Have you decided that?

Comment: Date would be a range. Lets say i wanted to search from the 5th till the 27th of the month. And another time id want to search from the 11th till the 24th. So date has to be a variable input so i dont go editing script each time, my original method semi works but only for 0-9, 10-19 etc.

Comment: I have added a simple way to enter the range and eval it.